# Wiring up Select Combobox using React/Redux not sending dispatch event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to initialise a select box using a Redux state store in my React website. The state store contains both a list of options available and a value representing the currently selected one.

When the select box is changed, I want it to fire an action event to the Redux store, telling it to perform some work based on what was selected.

However when I try and change the select combo box in the UI, it gives the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
>   ./src/GroupingSelector.tsx.GroupingSelector.onGroupingChange
>   C:/src/GroupingSelector.tsx:32   29 |        30 |     private
>   onGroupingChange(e: any) {   31 |          const { value } = e.target;
>
> > 32 |          this.props.dispatch({ type: 'UPDATEGROUPING', selectedOption: value });          33 |       }       34 | }   35 |

My class

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './App.css';
import IAction from './interfaces/IAction';

interface IGroupingProps {
    groupingOptions : string[],
    selectedGroupingOption : string,
    dispatch : any
  }

class GroupingSelector extends React.Component<IGroupingProps, {}> {

      public render() {

       return (
        <div className="Grouping-selector">
            <div className="Horizontal-panel-right Grouping-search-combo">
                <select onChange={this.onGroupingChange}>
                    {this.props.groupingOptions.map((name, index)=> 
                        <option key={index}>{name}</option>
                    )}
                </select>
            </div>
            <div className="Content Horizontal-panel-right">
                Group by
            </div>            
        </div>);
    }

    private onGroupingChange(e: any) {
         const { value } = e.target;
         const action: IAction<string> = {type: "UPDATEGROUPING", payload: value};
         this.props.dispatch(() => action);
      }    
}

function mapStateToProps(state: any) {
    return {
        groupingOptions: state.groupingOptions,
        selectedGroupingOption: state.selectedGroupingOption,
    };
  }    

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GroupingSelector);
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must dispatch a function.

```
 this.props.dispatch(() => { type: 'UPDATEGROUPING', selectedOption: value });
```

Although you should really consider having and *action.js* file and import it.

*action.js*

```
export const updateGrouping = (selectedOption) => {
  type: 'UPDATEGROUPING', 
  selectedOption
}
```

*Your class*

```
this.props.dispatch(updateGrouping(value))
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks to be the missing part. On your suggestion about having action.js as an exportable function value, how do I do the same in TS?

Comment: same, just action.ts instead.
Depending on your lint rules you might need to have default export. 
And types of course, my suggestion of Action type is to create generic: 
interface Action<T> {type: string; payload?: T }

Comment: Ok I've updated my code (edited above) for the change to pass a function, just the simple version first to get it working but I still get the same error about "TypeError: cannot read property 'props' of undefined. When I declared the "dispatch" in the IGroupingProps above as an explicit type Dispatcher<IAction<string>>, then it doesn't complain, however it then won't let me pass the function to this.props.dispatch(), it expects an IAction<string>, not () => IAction<string>

Comment: try make your connected props optional; 
interface IGroupingProps {
    groupingOptions?: string[],
    selectedGroupingOption?: string,
    dispatch?: any
  }

Comment: If that don't work try to declare dispatch as 
dispatch: (value: string) => void;